# React Js - Defining headers in the service

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-redux

I am a newbiew to ReactJs, need to know different ways by which we can include Headers in our service Url before making a call.

I am aware of how we used to make GET/POST Calls in angular Js after including headers...
Similarly want to know different ways to define headers in React Js, below is the sample of my component where i am making a service call.

There is a service Url which has few headers defined on Server side, how to include those headers on our side ...Sorry cant disclose the headers, please help me with some dummy headers data

```
componentDidMount(){
fetch('serviceURL')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(items=>{
    this.setState({
        items : items.contactNumber
    });
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const request = new Request('https://example.com/some-url', {
    headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    })
});

fetch(request).then(() => { /* handle response */ });
```

You can find more information about using `Headers` in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers).